# Create multiple worksheet in excel from xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to create an excel with multiple worksheet from a xslt. But i cant create more than one worksheet. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/> 

<xsl:template match="/">

<Worksheet ss:Protected="0" ss:Name="OBB Datos básicos">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th align="center" bgcolor="grey" colspan="6" ><font color="black">Detalle de la OBB</font></th>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<th align="left" bgcolor="white" colspan="1">Clase de operación:</th> 
</tr>
</table>
</Worksheet>

<Worksheet ss:Protected="0" ss:Name="Conceptos">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th align="center" bgcolor="grey" colspan="6" ><font color="black">Concepto</font></th>
</tr>
</table> 
</Worksheet>

</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code generates it:

[image]

Any idea how to create multiple worksheet in excel ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to missing the root element, I'm surprised it displays at all.

Add an `ss:WorkBook` (or `WorkBook` in your case), this may be enough, or check [this tutorial for more help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2005/06/27/433152.aspx) on missing parts in your structure.